# Mysql update row value in table based on different row

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mariadb

I have the following table structure

```
TABLE A   
    Productid    price   groupId  
     1             100      A
     2             99       A
     3              0       A
     4             50       B
     5             49       B
     6              0       B
```

I populate table A with prices from table B joining on Id. Sometimes table B doesn't have prices.
In cases were b doesn't have price I want to update the price to be another price from that same group, as I can't have a price of zero.

Is there an way to update table a price column using itself based on group? e.g. update productId 3 price to be the price of another product in it's group (1 or 2)

```
TABLE A after update  
Productid    price   groupId  
 1             100      A
 2             99       A
 3             100      A
 4             50       B
 5             49       B
 6             49       B
```

It seems silly but these are the business rules (it makes sense irl I simplified the problem for the example)

When  I tried the following I got Error:

```
    update 'Table A' t1
    join (select price ,groupId from 'table A' where Price > 0 group by 
    groupId) as t2
    on t1.groupId = t2.GroupId
    SET t1.Price = t2.Price
  
     (conn=58292) Can't reopen table: 'Table A'
```

I've thought of creating a third temporary table but that seems.... wrong? I am sure there must be a way to do this using update statement and joins

Comment: Is `tableA` a temporary table?

Comment: No, Table A is a permanent table

Answer (score 1):

I would phrase the query as:

```
update tablea a
inner join (select groupId, max(price) price from tablea group by groupId) a1 
    on a1.groupId = a.groupId
set a.price = a1.price
where a.price = 0 and a1.price > 0
```

Notes:

- the table name should be surrounded with single quotes (those stand for literal strings) - if your table name really contains spaces, then use backticks for quoting (or better, yet, fix the table name!)
- I changed the subquery to make it a valid aggregation query - yours has non-aggregated columns that do not belong to the `group by` clause, which is not a good practice, and might generate errors, depending on the SQL mode of your database

In this **[demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=46ea392085b802a0d67a1c73cc0e076c)** with your sample data, the content of the table after update is:

```
Productid | price | groupId
--------: | ----: | :------
        1 |   100 | A      
        2 |    99 | A      
        3 |   100 | A      
        4 |    50 | B      
        5 |    49 | B      
        6 |    50 | B
```

Comment: Thank! but I tried and got a similar error  '(conn=58516) Can't reopen table: 'a' ' ....
it might my db engine which is preventing the join?

Comment: @manicbubble: as far as I know, the error you are getting indicates that your table is a temporary table (as I originally commented on your question). Are you running MySQL or MariaDB? Which version exactly?